# Angularjs factory method implementation

Tags: angularjs

I am writing an angularjs factory to do some calculation. I named it as CalcEngineService This factory has one method which is used by controllers,directives. This factory method is called several hundreds of times.

My question is that the factory method requires collection of rules to do the calculation. I get this collection of rules from http service.When I use http call to get rules in side the method I see several hundreds of http calls and the performance is affected. How can I restrict the call to get rules collection to just once and also make sure any change to rules is also taken care of.

```
defaultRules = [];
function calculateDuedate(test) {

        getDefaultRules().then(function(rules){
       // DO calculations with rules and find the duedate and update test with duedate
});
        return test.dueDate;
    }

function getDefaultRules() {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (utility.isEmpty(defaultRules)) {
                rulesService.getDefaultRules().then(function (rules) {
                    defaultRules = rules.data;
                    resolve(defaultRules);
                });
            }
            else {
                resolve(defaultRules)
            }
        });
    }
```

I am fairly new to angularjs and dont know many features fully to take advantage of. Can anybody suggest a good way of handling this ?

Comment: Can you post the complete code of the service, and an example of usage. It's not clear (at least to me) from the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add some logic around your $http call, specifically once you've made one request don't make anymore. Wait for the one request to return and then continue your calculations.